# How to fix the error of this code: "dirac[:N / 2] = 1"?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

I got this python code from the internet, and it's for calculating the modulation spread function (MTF) from an input image. Here is the
[full code](https://github.com/habi/GlobalDiagnostiX/blob/master/MTF.py).

The problem is that the code is not functioning on my PC due to an error in this line :

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-035feef9e484> in <module>
     54 N = 250
     55 dirac = np.zeros(N)
---> 56 dirac[:N / 2] = 1
     57
     58 # Filter edge

TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

Comment: `dirac[:N // 2] = 1`, seems to be `python2` code.

Comment: oh, I have python 3, do you know how can I type it in python 3 ??

Answer (score 0):

Simply make N/2 an integer again.

```
dirac[:int(N/2)] = 1
```